# check all rows within an array if value exist

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if a value exists in an array property, an alert should pop up, if not it should log in the console. With my current code this is the results i'm getting

User Data Arrary

```
[{"primary_contact":"+1111111111","secondary_contact":null},{"primary_contact":"+2222222222","secondary_contact":"+2"}]
```

Code

```
for (let r = 0; r < this.global.userData.length; r++) {
  if (this.global.userData[r].primary_contact === this.formattedNumber1) {
    alert('Phone Number has been used already');
  } else {
    console.log('push data')
  }
}
```

When I sent `+1111111111` as the formattedNumber1 the alert pops up, but when I set `+2222222222` the alert doesn't pop up and it writes in the console but it should be able to pop up an alert cos `+2222222222` also exist in the array

Comment: Your array is invalid. Are you sure this is the one you're actually using or is it a typo?

Comment: There is a syntax error in the array itself, there is a random quote by null.

Comment: You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is invalid. I believe it is a typo. See below sample code where I have fixed your array.

Another alternative solution can be to make use [Array.Some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) :

```
let arr = [{
  "primary_contact": "+1111111111",
  "secondary_contact": null
  }, {
  "primary_contact": "+2222222222",
  "secondary_contact": "+2"
}];


function contactExists(contact) {
  return arr.some(function(el) {
    return el.primary_contact === contact;
   }); 
}

console.log(contactExists('+1111111111')); // true
console.log(contactExists('+2222222222')); // true
```